# Is possible to use nanosleep in a infinite loop with select()?

Tags: c, select, for-loop, sleep

I have a **C** program that do recv/send operations from/to socket using a `for(;;)` loop and a `select()` to monitor the file descriptor. I need also this program to send a packet every 80msec to a packet, how can I implement this? 
Maybe I can use a `fork()` and the child process simply write an ack in one of the file descriptor monitored by the `select()` every 80msec.
Is there better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling select() you can use the timeout argument to limit the selection waiting time.

```
 struct timeval {
           long    tv_sec;         /* seconds */
           long    tv_usec;        /* microseconds */
       };

int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
              fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

It is rather easy to limit the timeout to 80msec and send the required packet.

Comment: The problem is the select() returns several time in 80msec and I can't re utilize the timeval sturct with the remaining time for portability reason (only linux do it right)...